# Entity Design with a table having only foreign keys

Tags: jpa, mapping

How can I design entity for the following table design.

[image]

Since I had issue with handling the MAP table relation in entities, I had added a RUN_ID for that table which is actually not  required and bad design.

[image]

So can some one help in creating an Entity design.

I do have the following doubts.
1. Do I need to create a separate Embeddable key entity for MAP table ?
2. Here I don't need to insert TYPE_MAST table each time, I can use existing value and add that into REQ_TYPE_MAP table.How can I achieve this ?

Comment: There shouldn't be any entity for this table. There should simply be a OntoMany or ManyToMany association between the two entities, mapped by this join table. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-many-to-many

Comment: @JB Nizet : This solution doesn't work in my case. Here to persist I need to make an insert in both the Request and Type_Mast table every time. Here the third table is just a mapping table to tell request had choose which maser. So I feel I need to maintain that RUN_ID in third table. ?

Comment: It does work for everyone else, so it should work with you too. If it doesn't, then tell precisely what you want to achieve, post the code of the two entities and of the code you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's very simple.

For request:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="Request")
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @Data
    public class Request {

        private Long requestId;

        private String movileNo;

        private String civilId;

        @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
        @JoinTable(
                name = "Employee_Project",
                joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "request_id") },
                inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "type_id") }
        )
        private Set typeMast;


    }
```

and for TypeMast

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "type_mast")
    public class TypeMast {    
        // ...  

        @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "typeMast")
        private Set request;

        // standard constructors/getters/setters   
    }
```

Comment: So the request format will be like this ?<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

 
 <civilId>11468948</civilId>
 <mobileNo>861122</mobileNo>
 
   <typeMast >
  <typeId>5</typeId>
 </typeMast >
 <typeMast >
  <typeId>6</typeId>
 </typeMast >

Comment: @user630209 JPA has nothing to do with XML and requests. It's about persistence. Send whatever you want in your request, and in the code handling the request, do whatever you need to do with your entities.

Comment: JB Nizet : Hibernate: insert into request (civilid, mobile_no) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into type_master (name, type_id) values (?, ?).................These are the queries generated and thrown ConstraintViolationException as expected. Here I dont want to trigger the second query. there is no insert happening in master. DO I need to add a seperate question for that ?

Comment: I think I need to use a RUN_ID ?. My requirement is different. There is no insert happening to the type_master table every time. Please suggest,